# Plugin for Jenkins to easily add additional actions to job

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

Is there a plug-in that let me add custom additional actions to Jenkins' jobs. I'd like to have additional buttons in left column just like Maven release plugin adds "Perform Maben Release". I'd like to have things like "Put on QA server", "Run Sonar Analysis" etc.

I know I can create separate jobs, but I'd like to share the same workspace.

It could run the parametrized build with predefined parameters or run custom maven goal.

Comment: There is a batch task plugin

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Would you mind putting an answer instead of a comment so I could accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [batch task plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Batch+Task+Plugin).

Comment: Doesn't seem to support pipeline builds, unfortunately